# Is a transit visa needed to transfer in Boryspil airport?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, ukraine, chinese-citizens

My wife, a Chinese citizen living in the United Kingdom under a spousal visa, will be travelling from London to Beijing next summer. She has a layover at Boryspil Airport for a little over 4 hours.

She is flying both into and out of the airport with Ukraine International Airlines, which [on their website](http://www.flyuia.com/eng/information-and-services/Important-information/terminalF.html) says that all of its flights arrive and depart from Terminal D.

I [read on VisaHQ](https://ukraine.visahq.co.uk/requirements/China/resident-United_Kingdom/#!ukraine-transit-visa) that a transit visa is needed for Chinese citizens. However, I also read that [if you are not changing terminal in Kiev, no transit visa is needed](https://www.tripadvisor.ie/ShowTopic-g294474-i3663-k6628249-4_hours_transit_at_airport_do_i_need_a_visa-Kiev.html), but no evidence seems to be offered for that claim.

Is a transit visa required if she stays in Terminal D for the entirety of the layover? If not, where are the official sources stating that staying in the terminal is permissible without such a visa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strange choice of transit but not mine.

There is no visa required for transit as long as don't leave the terminal.  All international departures happen in terminal D and the visa information from [Timatic](http://www.skyteam.com/en/Why-SkyTeam/Services/Visa-and-Health/) is as follows:

> China - Destination Passport
>
> Passport required.
>
> Document validity rules:
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on
>   arrival.
>
> Type: Ok China - Destination Visa
>
> Additional information:
>
> Valid visas or resident permits in expired passports are accepted if
>   holding valid passport of the same nationality.
>
> Type: Notice China - Destination Health
>
> This information is for guide purposes only. Other health
>   organisations may recommend alternative precautions.
>
> Passengers arriving within 6 days after leaving or transiting
>   countries with risk of yellow fever transmission and not holding a
>   yellow fever vaccination certificate are subject to vaccination upon
>   arrival. At the airport of Dalian (DLC) passenger will be kept in
>   quarantine for 10 days or deported.
>
> Exempt from Yellow Fever vaccination:
>
> Children under 9 months of age.
>
> Recommended Health and Vaccination precautions:
>
> Malaria prophylaxis. Malaria risk, including P. falciparum, exists in
>   Yunnan and Hainan. P. falciparum resistance to chloroquine and
>   sulfadoxine-pyrimethamine reported. Limited risk of P. vivax malaria
>   exists in southern and some central provinces. There is no malaria
>   risk in the urban areas. Recommended prevention in risk areas: B; in
>   Hainan and Yunnan: C.
>
> In Timatic, the recommended type of prevention is referred to as: 
>   - Type A (very limited risk of malaria transmission) - Mosquito bite prevention only.
>   - Type B (risk of P. vivax malaria only) - Mosquito bite prevention plus chloroquine chemoprophylaxis.
>   - Type C (risk of P. falciparum malaria with chloroquine and sulfadoxine-pyrimethamine resistance) - Mosquito bite prevention plus
>   atovaquone-proguanil or doxycyline or mefloquine chemoprophylaxis.
>   - Type D (risk of P. falciparum malaria plus reported multi-drug resistance) - Mosquito bite prevention plus plus atovaquone-proguanil
>   or doxycyline or mefloquine chemoprophylaxis, depending on local drug
>   restistance. Chemoprophylaxis should be started preferably one week
>   before departure and no later than the first day of exposure; it must
>   be taken with unfailing regularity and continued for 4 weeks after the
>   last exposure. No prophylactic regimen is 100% protective against
>   infection, but even if it fails to prevent the disease it may,
>   nevertheless, render the infection milder and less life threatening.
>
> Type: Notice Ukraine - Transit Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> **Transiting without a visa is possible for:**
>
> **Holders of onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours through
>   Kiev Boryspil (KBP).**
>
> Type: Ok Ukraine - Transit Health
>
> This information is for guide purposes only. Other health
>   organisations may recommend alternative precautions.
>
> Vaccinations not required.

Comment: It's "strange" because it's 800 pounds cheaper than the next cheapest ticket ;-) As you can tell, the optimisation here is for cost. Thanks for the clarification! I will wait on getting a more official source from the Ukranian government or similar, but if that doesn't come up I'll accept this one.